# Keep Sending Request if no Response

Tags: javascript, httpresponse

How can I keep fetching the webpage while it didn't get response being in a loop?

```js
for (el of NodeList) {
  const url = el.getAttribute('href')
  const res = await fetch(url) //if no response, below code won't execute
  const html = await response.text()
  const parser = new DOMParser()
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html')
  alert('parsed successfully')
}
```

So as it works in a loop and sends very many requests at a time, even a small and short issue with network can spoil the whole process, what can I do?

Comment: Why not send a single request? Whats the point of sending a whole bunch or requests at the same time?

Comment: how about something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44054597/6567275

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop

Try something like this (not tested)

```js
const processText = (arr) => console.log(arr.doc);

let nList = [...NodeList].map(({href}) => ({ href,done:false,doc:"" }));
const getData = () => {
  if (nList.length === 0) {
    processText(nList); // here you loop over the docs in the object
    return;
  }
  const current = nList[0];
  const res = fetch(current.href)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    const parser = new DOMParser()
    current.doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html')
  })
  .done(() => {
    current.done = true;
    console.log(current.href,'parsed successfully')
    nList = nList.filter(({done}) => !done);
  })
  .always(() => setTimeout(getData,2000)); // try next (or again)
}
getData();
```

Comment: How will this work if you didn't define neither url, nor processText()?

Comment: Sorry, `const res = fetch(current.href)` - and processText is something that YOU need to write. It takes the array of doc and processes it. You did not tell us what you wanted to do with the docs. You just alert "parsed successfully".

Comment: Sorry I just didn't get how it parses every href of NodeList elements. NodeList elements are simply `a` tags, from where I need only values of `href` attribute. What I'll do with docs after isn't important

Comment: `let nList = [...NodeList].map(({href}) => ({ href,done:false,doc:"" }));` creates an array of objects: `[{ "href":"https://.....", "done": false, doc = "" },{ "href":"https://.....", "done": false, doc = "" },...]` and after you have `[{ "href":"https://.....", "done": true, doc = "text of url" },{ "href":"https://.....", "done": true, doc = "text of next url" },...]`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should handle network errors. Try to do this with retry mechanism that tries to fetch the webpage again if no response is received.

You can make function fetchWithRetry that takes two arguments: the URL to fetch and the maximum number of retries (to avoid infinite loop).

```
async function fetchWithRetry(url, numberOfRetries) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const html = await response.text();
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    alert('parsed successfully');
    return doc;
  } catch (error) {
    if (numberOfRetries > 0) {
      console.error('Error fetching webpage. Retrying...', error);
      return fetchWithRetry(url, numberOfRetries - 1);
    } else {
      console.error('Error fetching webpage. Maximum retries exceeded.', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can modify your code to use the fetchWithRetry function instead of the fetch function.

```
for (el of NodeList) {
  const url = el.getAttribute('href');
  const doc = await fetchWithRetry(url, 3);
  // Do something with the parsed document
}
```